# Changing an objects property (in a different class) from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This is what I'm trying to do: User launches app. `AppDelegate` creates a reference to the existing instance of `SecondClass`. Then, the string of a label initialized on `SecondClass` is changed.

I've tried two approaches to this:

**First approach:**

*AppDelegate:*

```
CCScene *scene2 = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"FirstClass"];
FirstClass *firstClass = (FirstClass *)scene2.children.firstObject;
[firstClass changeLabel];
```

*FirstClass*

```
@implementation FirstClass
{
    CCLabelTTF *myLabel
}

-(void)changeLabel
{
    myLabel.string = @"String";
}
```

**Second Approach:**
*AppDelegate:*

```
CCScene *scene2 = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"FirstClass"];
FirstClass *firstClass = (FirstClass *)scene2.children.firstObject;
firstClass.myLabel.string = @"String";
```

*FirstClass*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CCLabelTTF *myLabel;
```

Both of these approaches end in the same result.. The labels string does not change. When I used the same exact code to change an NSInteger, instead of label string, and then use NSLog to print it out and it worked. I've triple checked to make sure that `myLabel` is not nil. I've also made sure that `myLabel` is not running on a background thread. I'm trying to understand how to make it work and I'd really appreciate any answers to make this work. Thank you.

EDIT:
I edited `changeLabel` to create a new NSString called `newString` and set `newString` to "new string". Then I set `adsPrice.string` to `newString` but it STILL isn't displaying the new string, even though I have an NSLog telling me what `newString` is.

Comment: Where are you instantiating myLabel? Perhaps it's null?

Comment: both should work unless myLabel isn't the label you are looking at, or you have two instances of firstclass

Comment: I placed a breakpoint where I set the string of myLabel, and it is not nil. If I try to set the string of `myLabel` directly from `FirstClass` it works just fine, for example in the `init` method. Also, if I print the NSLog `NSLog(@"%@", firstClass.myLabel.string);` it outputs as `String` so the string of the label IS being changed, but I can't see the updated label on the UI for some reason

Comment: I edited `changeLabel` to create a new NSString called `newString` and set `newString` to "new string". Then I set `adsPrice.string` to `newString` but it STILL isn't displaying the new string, even though I have an NSLog telling me what `newString` is.